# How to check when added a new line in log file - Java

Tags: java, logging

I'm trying monitoring the log file using my simple script in java.
How to check whether a file has changed when script is run again.
The script should check occurred is the phrase "Unable"
My script is running every 5 minutes (Windows Scheduler)

My code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


   public class LogAgent {

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
      double count = 0,countBuffer=0,countLine=0;
      String lineNumber = "";
      String filePath = "/Users/Radek/log.txt";
      BufferedReader br;
      String inputSearch = "Unable";
      String line = "";

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    try {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            countLine++;
            //System.out.println(line);
            String[] words = line.split(" ");

            for (String word : words) {
              if (word.equals(inputSearch)) {
                count++;
                countBuffer++;
              }
            }

            if(countBuffer > 0)
            {
                countBuffer = 0;
                lineNumber += countLine + ",";
            }

        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    if (count == 0)
    {
         System.out.println("Stan poprawny");
    }
    else
    {
System.out.println("Liczba wystapien alertu--"+count);
// System.out.println("Alert w liniach--"+lineNumber);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using a similar system where the "log agent" keeps its own log on how many bytes it has read from the log file it monitors. So every time you run the agent, you write the number of bytes into another file. When the agent is launched, it reads back in the number of bytes and skips that many bytes before reading the actual log file again. It works well, I'd recommend that. Alternatively you could save the number of lines read instead of bytes and then use that.